# extract statement from unformatted text file

Tags: oracle

I have a text PL/SQL file and doesn't have any delimiters between statements. I need to find statements without specific delimiters between them.

for example I have tow statement like this

```
ALTER TABLE XXX ADD XX NUMBER(4)
CREATE INDEX XXX ON XX(
   XXX ASC
) TABLESPACE %IDX%
```

this problem related to human mistake, and I need to remove human mistake.

I expect result like this

1. statement one
   ALTER TABLE XXX ADD XX NUMBER(4) **/**
2. statement two
   CREATE INDEX XXX ON XX(XXX ASC) TABLESPACE %IDX% **/**

has any framework application ... for this !?

Comment: I'm lost.  Your code is not T-SQL.  It looks like Oracle code.  What database are you really using?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: This sounds like you're saying you have a text file with other *stuff* in it, and you want *something* to automagically detect any SQL statements in said file, and the automagically execute those statements against your (Oracle) SQL instance. Those "automagic" *things* are called Humans, and they'll need to read the file, and extract the relevant lines out, and but them into well formatted sql files.

Comment: Put semicolon `;` after each statement in the text file and then save it as `.sql` and execute in SQL command prompt or `sql developer` as script and you are done.

Comment: For a one-time task, SQL Developer or SQL\*Plus are the usual tools for running sets of commands against a server. If you need to repeatedly read files, split commands, and run them one-at-a-time, like building your own SQL Fiddle, then look at my open source program [plsql_lexer](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer/). The complex example in the readme file shows a relevant example. But no matter what tool you use you need to have predefined delimiters between statements, usually `;` after SQL and `/` after PL/SQL. Please edit your question and add more details about what you need.

Comment: Jon Heller Thanks and your program is amazing . but I think, it split statement by  delimiters is that correct ?  my problem return to human mistake and i want to remove it.

Comment: @MohamadSefati You could possibly loop through the lines of the file backwards, see if the lines are valid according to the package STATEMENT_CLASSIFIER, and add a delimiter if the package can identify the command. But that would only find missing delimiters, not other syntax errors. And there's an infinite amount of potential ambiguity that cannot be easily solved. For example: `select * from dual \n commit`. Is that a single select statement with a table alias, or is it one select statement followed by a commit command? Not many programming problems can be automatically corrected.

Comment: @MohamadSefati, Please ask your question with better and more tags here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/ ;-)